# When are generic functions necessary or desired in Swift?

Tags: generics, swift, coding-style

Apple's Swift [language documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html) provides the following example of the use of *generic functions* and *type parameters* (under the section on "Type Constraints in Action"):

```
func findIndex<T: Equatable>(array: [T], valueToFind: T) -> Int? {
    for (index, value) in enumerate(array) {
        if value == valueToFind {
            return index
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Is the use of either necessary here? Isn't

```
func findIndex(array: [Equatable], valueToFind: Equatable) -> Int? {
    for (index, value) in enumerate(array) {
        if value == valueToFind {
            return index
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

equivalent? If not, what am I missing? If so is there a reason for preferring the former over the latter or a general rule of thumb for deciding to use generic functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two aren't equivalent. The generic function is saying you can call this function with two parameters: an array of `T` and a value to find, which is also of type `T`, and adds a constraint that `T` must be `Equatable`. (Without that constraint, the `value == valueToFind` comparison wouldn't compile.)

The second function simply requires that the array be of instances that are `Equatable` and that the value to find be `Equatable`, so theoretically you could call it with an `[String]` array and an `Int`, which would end up making the equality comparison not make sense.

(Moreover, Swift places limits on using protocols as types when the protocol uses `Self` in any of its declarations or has an associated type alias, so the second example won't compile, either, but that's not the main difference between a protocol-based function and a generic.)

All this points to two scenarios that will necessitate creating a generic function:

1. You want the function to be available to all types that conform to a protocol, but that protocol can't be used as a type (like `Equatable`, or nearly any other Swift protocol, to be honest).
2. You need to have a relationship between two or more different parameters of a function, such that they need to be of the same type or a related type.

Your example fits both these criteria, but even if Swift didn't place the limit that requires generics in case #1, case #2 would still apply.

Comment: (Yes, probably a bad example to illustrate my question; but you saw through it to the main point, #2.)

Comment: So the key thing is the enforcement of the relationship: `array` and `valueToFind` must be the *same* `Equatable`. Right?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Right. If you take a peek at the [top-level functions in Swift](http://swifter.natecook.com/global/) you'll see a huge variety of ways of defining those relationships.

Comment: So if I didn't have a relationship to impose (say I had one argument for example, or two different types T and U), there would be situations where the two approaches were equivalent?

Comment: As long as you aren't running afoul of #1 - all the Objective-C protocols, like `UITableViewDelegate`, are fine in this regard. A function that needed to act on a delegate could be generic or accept the parameter with the protocol as its type.

Comment: @NateCook can you please elaborate why second example is not compile able.Thanks for your help `protocol uses Self in any of its declarations` what does this mean

Answer (score 1):

I agree, those two look equivalent, however your second example does not compile:

> error: protocol 'Equatable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

The issue is due to the use of `Self` in the `Equatable` protocol.